# Why are mid wards effective?

Tags: dota-2

On this [match](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEA9pjm3cUY) between Miracle and w33, Miracle (on the dire side) placed his wards on his side of the mid, center atop the ledge. (2:02 minutes into the vid)

I noticed other high level mid players do this too. Why is that?

I understand he did this so that he could see w33's side of the mid lane, but there are better places to put that ward. For example, at the **upper left side of the radiant side**. In this way, you can also **see the top rune and watch out for ganks**, while having vision of the mid lane.

**EDIT** Here is an illustration of the map, with the red X being the ward placement seen in the vid, and the green X being what I think should have been the better ward placement[image]

Why is the Red X a good Placement for wards nowadays?

Comment: Mid is the most active lane and intel from there is probably critical.

Comment: That really is a weird placement. I would understand putting it on the radiant side to see when the enemy mid is missing (possibly to gank somewhere), but placing it on your own side? Huh...

Comment: Was it normal ward or sentry? Btw which heroes were they playing?

Comment: Well, pros do like to place wards in weird places, just so that they won't be dewarded as easily (since the enemy thought it would be placed elsewhere and miss it with a sentry). It's also possible that it was just done because he felt he needed the ward in the moment and placed it right then, because he couldn't simply leave the lane. When you move out of your way, it also usually is a sign for the enemy that you just placed a ward.

Comment: Well, if your ward vanishes from your inventory, it is also a sign for the enemy that you just placed a war @Bexo :P

Comment: @FlorianPeschka Placing it on your own side reduces the vision, but also reduces the likelihood of it getting dewarded.  It's easy to deward if it's on the enemy side of the river, and it's quite common to ward in mid these days.  Placing on your own side protects you slightly from ganks at your sides.

Comment: This ward position will cover your ass when your wave is pushing the tower (and you are too). Normally a support can sneak in through the woods to the north or east, and cut your retreat. With the red ward in place, you see when that happens, the green ward only protects you from stupid supports moving in through the river junction.

Comment: @antipattern you can also cover your ass by placing the green X ward on your side of the map. You can also see the top rune there. BUT.. then again you won't have enemy vision of mid. Huh.

Comment: Well...yes, thats exactly the point. Not sure of the match as I have not seen it, but they probably had another ward at the rune.

Answer (score 4):

Uphill wards like the one you have seen in the match are placed to have vision of your opponent rather than the lane itself. If your creeps are fighting in the river, you have no sight of what is happening uphill.

If you want to prevent being killed by ganks, or have an enemy like pudge, having uphill vision in the midlane is very benificial.

Fitting to this situation: placing the ward on your side of the river increases your chances that it is not going to be dewarded, while placing it on predictable places, a sentry will get rid of your ward.

Answer (score 2):

All these pro players know each others secret places of placing the ward. So it's always useful to change your way of placing wards. If the ward is placed on the green mark then u don't get vision on your side cliff at all at the night time because of the trees. And also since the ward is placed near you so if the opponent wants to deward by hitting it then it's not possible and if you are fast enough to take out the ward with quelling blade or tango. Somehow you just want to reduce the enemies farm since at the start of a game dewarding gives you a huge boost in xp and 50 gold.